# How to add media type to stylesheet reference asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using asp mvc, and I'm using the following code to generate the CSS html reference:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

which generates the following html:

```
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and that works fine. However, I need to add media type as an additional attribute. How can I go about using this style.render to add attributes to the generated html? Should I be thinking about making the change in the bundle config instead?

edit: I would like the end product to look like this:

```
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" media="handheld"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `@Styles.RenderFormat()` for that:

```
@Styles.RenderFormat(@"<link href=""{0}""
                             rel=""stylesheet""
                             media=""handheld"" />",
                      "~/Content/css")
```

Comment: Ah thanks. This should be it... do you know if there's an API for stuff like this somewhere? Every time I search I just get a very specific blog post that often is too specific to find an answer like this

Comment: This whole 'Bundling and Minification' package is part of the `ASP.NET Web Optimization` effort (if i get it right, it is developed in Microsoft but by a separate team), you can find their official page at http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
< link href="@Styles.Url("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

Comment: I like this better. Much cleaner. +1

Comment: I prefer this answer as RenderFormat is best when you want to dynamically add extra string to the css, eg. you want to dynamically set the media based on certain conditions. +1 for this answer.