# CSS-styled <figure> of circle will not display in print-view

Tags: html, css, printing, background, figure

I have created some 3D spheres with figure html elements and css-styling that I cannot get to display in a print-view. I am trying in both IE9 as well as Chrome v45. What can I do to get these to print? I hope the answer is not to change the element to something other than figure as this would require numerous other changes.

I have
-- checked "print background colors an images" in IE print dialogue and I've checked "background graphics" in Chrome print dialogue.
-- tried adding -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; to a number of places in the css, including figure{}, .sphere{} and .red{}
-- tried adding a print-backgrounds chrome extension, which I later learned was obsolete anyway.

HTML:

```
<figure class="red sphere"></figure>
```

CSS for Chrome:

```
.sphere {
  display: block; 
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px auto auto auto;  
}

.red {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 10px, red, #000);  
}
```

CSS for IE9:

```
.sphere {
  display: block;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 5px auto auto auto;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100, finishopacity=40, style=2);
}

.red {
    background: red; 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing, after nearly 3 years I was finally asked (again) to create a print view for the MVC application in question here. So I googled my question (again) and thought 'this person is asking just what I'm after!'. Yep, turns out it was my own question (and still unanswered) ...

Gained from my own experience, and searching other code I'd written since first asking my question, here is the answer,  ...

```
@media print
{
    .red {
        background: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 10px, red, #000) !important;  
    }

    .yellow {
        background: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 10px, yellow, #000) !important;  
    }

    .green {
        background: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 10px, #00af00, #000) !important;  
    }

}
```

Yep, I just had to re-describe the background color characteristics (and include !important) in the @media print section of the css file. Why? Idk. It's a direct copy/paste (plus !important) of the general css section. But it worked!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When linking your stylesheet make sure to have `media=all` in the link.

It should look something like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css">`

or set up a specific `print` stylesheet like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">`

Comment: Do you know how to do that in MVC bundles? bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/myStyleSheet.css"));

Comment: [check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256121/how-to-add-media-type-to-stylesheet-reference-asp-mvc) - hopefully that helps

Comment: @lincstar182 what did you try? adding a `media` rule or the link I posted? Please elaborate on what `it` is.

Comment: I tried both. But I'm using Visual Studio 2012, which does not support Styles.RenderFormat. So I broke my css out of the bundle, and tried your media rule, directly in the html.

Comment: @lincstar182 hrmm, maybe you need a html 5 [printshiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv-printshiv/) - you can include it in your [modernizr build](https://modernizr.com) as well, if you're using it

Comment: Thanks for reminder about shiv. It is included in my modernizer bundle, but I added the latest explicitly. It did not help any. Still can't use Styles.RenderFormat and still no visible globes in print view. Thanks for trying to help.